# Unexpected token in valid RegEx when running webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've defined the following RegEx in a util file in a react / redux application:

This works fine, and doesn't cause any fails to compile if I declare it as a string:

```
export const REGEX_VALID_URL =
  '^(https?://(www.)?)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?$';
```

However, if I declare it as a regular expression literal like so:

```
 export const VALID_URL =
      /^(https?://(www.)?)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?$/;
```

Webpack will fail to compile, and shows this error:
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (2:19)

```
  1 | export const VALID_URL =
> 2 |   /^(https?://(www.)?)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?$/;
    |                    ^
```

What is the issue here, and how do I get webpack to see this RegEx as Aok?

Comment: You probably just need to escape your /s

Comment: Can you show an example? Which /s?

Comment: Well, because you are using / as your delimiter, you will need to escape any within the regex with a \
/^(https?:\/\/(www.)?)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/

Comment: That solved it! If you want to, submit the answer and I'll mark as accepted, otherwise I can self answer. Thanks!

Comment: you can also use `new RegExp(REGEX_VALID_URL);`

Comment: @OlivierBoissé There's a potential performance improvement when using the RegEx literal, and that's why I've opted for it here. I had previously used strings and the new RegExp(REGEX) syntax, which also works great.

Comment: @zero_cool I will never turn down the chance at having my answer accepted lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using / as your delimiter, you will need to escape any within the regex with a \

```
/^(https?:\/\/(www.)?)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$/
```

Should be all you need.